# How to pass localized message from server to client?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have spring-mvc application.

On the server side inside controller methode I have wrote the following code:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource
                        .getMessage("Common.wrongFileFormatOrSizeLimitExceeded", null, LOCALE_RU),
                        HttpStatus.NOT_EXTENDED);
```

On the server side in debug I see that

```
messageSource.getMessage("Common.wrongFileFormatOrSizeLimitExceeded", null, LOCALE_RU)
```

returns properly localized message.

on the client side I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        ....
        error: function (data) { 
                    console.log(data.responseText);
               }
```

The client code write the following message to console:

> ???????????????????????????????????????

When I pass latin message from server - code works properly.

How to pass localized message from server to client ?

Comment: `LOCALE_RU` is it Russian ? try in different browsers if your `messages.*` file is configured correctly and you are certain back-end is sending it. Can you make cut down version of this app which may be I (or others interested ) can run to reproduce it.

Comment: **messages.* file** what is it ?

Comment: The message is probably correct, however encoding is not. Please make sure that you're using UTF-8 everywhere. And I mean **evereywhere** (i.e. `<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'></script>`).